# Markov chain model in R: returning 0 conversion value

Tags: r, markov, attribution

I am running a Markov chain model in R with the sample data below:

[image]

There are clearly conversion values. However when I check the model output,  conversion values are zeros.

Do you know what happened in the process and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you please review how to ask a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. Without one, this question will probably be closed. Please do not post code in screenshots

Comment: Can you provide the code that produced this output? Is it something like `markov_model(df, var_path = "Path1", var_conv = "conversion", var_value = "value")`?